# Google Cloud: cannot access SignUp page of my DjangoApp

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In my Django APP I've a SignUp section that I cannot access because of error 500:

**Server Error (500)**.

I've made a ping request to this section:

```
ping stickersgallito.pe/account/create/
```

And terminal response is:

```
Ping request could not find host stickersgallito.pe/account/create/. Please check the name and try again.
```

Of course I can make a ping to just the host name and get a response:

```
(stickers_gallito) D:\web_proyects\stickers_gallito>ping stickersgallito.pe

Pinging stickersgallito.pe [35.211.238.73] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 35.211.238.73: bytes=32 time=114ms TTL=67
Reply from 35.211.238.73: bytes=32 time=120ms TTL=67
Reply from 35.211.238.73: bytes=32 time=136ms TTL=67
Reply from 35.211.238.73: bytes=32 time=136ms TTL=67

Ping statistics for 35.211.238.73:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 114ms, Maximum = 136ms, Average = 126ms
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('shop.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
    path('order/', include('order.urls')),
    path('account/create/', views.signupView, name = 'signup'),
    path('account/login/', views.signinView, name = 'signin'),
    path('account/logout/', views.signoutView, name = 'signout'),
    path('province/', views.get_province, name = 'province')
]
```

**Google Cloud Logs:**

I don't see any error in the logs:

[image]

**views.py:**

```
@transaction.atomic
def signupView(request):
    peru = Peru.objects.all()
    department_list = set()
    province_list = set()
    district_list = set()
    for p in peru:
        department_list.add(p.departamento)
    department_list = list(department_list)
    # print("Department List: ", department_list)
    if len(department_list):
        province_list = set(Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0]).values_list("provincia", flat=True))
        # print("Provice List: ", province_list)
        province_list = list(province_list)
        # print("dfsfs", province_list)
    else:
        province_list = set()
    if len(province_list):
        district_list = set(
            Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0], provincia=province_list[0]).values_list("distrito",
                                                                                                         flat=True))
        # print("district List: ", district_list)
    else:
        district_list = set()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("INSIDE REQUEST.POST")
        print("Department List: ", department_list)
        print("Provice List: ", province_list)
        print("district List: ", district_list)
        print("REQUEST")
        print(request.POST)

        #####

        peru = Peru.objects.all()
        department_list = set()
        province_list = set()
        district_list = set()
        for p in peru:
            department_list.add(p.departamento)
        department_list = list(department_list)
        print("Department List in POST: ", department_list)
        if len(department_list):
            province_list = set(
                Peru.objects.filter(departamento__in=department_list).values_list("provincia", flat=True))

            province_list = list(province_list)
            print("Province LIST in POST", province_list)
        else:
            province_list = set()
        if len(province_list):
            district_list = set(
                Peru.objects.filter(departamento__in=department_list, provincia__in=province_list).values_list("distrito",
                                                                                                             flat=True))
            print("District LIST in POST", district_list)
        else:
            district_list = set()


        #####

        user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        # profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST) #__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'province_list' and 'department_list'
        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST)
        # profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST, instance=user.profile)


        if  user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            signup_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name='Clientes')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)
            raw_password = user_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.refresh_from_db()  # This will load the Profile created by the Signal
            # print(user_form.cleaned_data)
            print("Form is valid: district_list, province_list, department_list")
            print(district_list, province_list, department_list)
            profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST,
                                       instance=user.profile)  # Reload the profile form with the profile instance
            profile_form.full_clean()  # Manually clean the form this time. It is implicitly called by "is_valid()" method
            # print(profile_form.cleaned_data)
            profile_form.save()  # Gracefully save the form

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

        else:
            print("INVALID USeR_FORM")
            print(user_form.errors)
            print("INVALID Profile_FORM")
            print(profile_form.errors)

    else:

        user_form = SignUpForm()

        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list)
        print("GET PART!!!!!!")
        print("Deparment_List in GET: ", department_list)
        print("Province_List in GET: ", province_list)
        print("District_List in GET: ", district_list)
        # print('end of profile postdata print')
        # print(profile_form)
        # print("Profile Data:")

    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

Comment: If your app is not in production or if you can deploy it in a non-production environment, you can set `DEBUG = True` in your "settings.py" file so that you get the information when you access the /account/create page instead of just getting the '500' error which is too general. I'm not familiar with Django but I'm trying to find the cause of the issue. The 'debug' option will give a lot of useful information.

Comment: For example, if the template 'accounts/signup.html' doesn't exist, it will give you a 'Server Error (500)' unless you enable `DEBUG` where it will tell you "TemplateDoesNotExist at /account/create". Btw are you sure the template is in 'accounts/signup.html' and not in 'account/signup.html' (without the final 's')